# Can something be incomplete without starting something first?

Tags: ambiguity

I'm just curious about this word. The definition of *incomplete* is:

- not having all the necessary or appropriate parts.
- not full or finished.

Comment: Usually the use of "incomplete" means some of the parts are present or something has been started. An incomplete jigsaw puzzle normally would only be missing a small number of parts.

Comment: can you have an "incomplete" jigsaw puzzle if you have none of the parts?

Comment: Or say you have a list of chores, that you have no plan to ever start/complete. Are these chores incomplete or would you had to have made some progress on this list for it to be considered incomplete?

Comment: According to the definition you gave, yes, but it would be very rare usage. It might be used in your second example to mislead your parents into thinking you had started, without actually lying.

Comment: If you don’t have any jigsaw pieces, how do you know that what you have is even a jigsaw puzzle? Maybe you have an incomplete luxury yacht.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is reasonably posed from the perspective of the second of the meanings of *incomplete* given, for example, by Collins:

> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/incomplete)
> incomplete, adjective:
>
> 1. lacking a part or parts; not whole; not full
> 2. unfinished; not concluded
> 3. not perfect; not thorough

In meaning 2, that which is not finished (and which was therefore necessarily started), is incomplete.

The other meanings have no overtones or requirements of starting.

Meaning 1: I have a set of plumbing spanners that was advertised to cover a domestic size range from 4 to 28 mm. The the 22 mm spanner slot is empty so the set is incomplete {= lacking a part} until the shop corrects the error.

Meaning 3: because of the ugly caravan parked next to us, the view of the beautiful mountains is incomplete {not perfect}.

Comment: But even in sense 1 and 3, there **is** something existing which is incomplete, which suggests that for something to be incomplete, it must exist in the first place. Is the formation of Earth's second moon incomplete when it has never begun to form?

Comment: @AndrewLeach I too felt that existence (whether by pre-definition, hypothesis as with your neat second moon example, or simple fact) is indeed implied, but that it does not necessarily imply starting anything, unless one takes a very long view indeed, involving religion and philosophic underpinnings.

Answer (score 3):

One would not normally use ***incomplete*** for something that had not even been started. *Incomplete* is a bit like *unfinished*.

*Incomplete* suggests to me that something is "partially complete". It is also less likely to be used for something which has been barely begun. It is more frequently used for things which are "nearing completion".

That is not to rule out the possibility that it could on rare occasions be used to describe something not begun - it would not be technically incorrect to do so. On a check-list, for example, there may be one box for complete and one for incomplete, without any consideration for "not begun". In such a circumstance the *not begun* items would fall in the category of *incomplete*.

I checked the OED, which simply defines *incomplete* as something *not complete*, and does not go into the question of whether it can be used for something not begun.

So what I have said is simply based on my own experience over a lifetime as a native speaker.